# Why does this JUnitTest fail?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert

```
    @Test
public void testAscendingNumbers() {
    Object[][] testData = new Object[][]{
        {new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 4, 30},
        {new int[]{1, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 4, 0},
        {new int[]{1, 1, 1, 4, 3}, 5, 0},
        {new int[]{1, 2, 4, 3, 1}, 4, 30},
        {new int[]{2, 3, 4, 6, 1}, 5, 0},
        {new int[]{1, 2, 6, 4, 5}, 4, 0},
        {new int[]{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 4, 30},
        {new int[]{6, 5, 3, 4, 2}, 5, 40},
        {new int[]{2, 2, 3, 4, 4}, 4, 30},
        {new int[]{2, 6, 3, 5, 3}, 4, 40}
    };

    KniffelTableModel instance = new KniffelTableModel();
    for (Object[] obj : testData) {
        System.out.println((int) obj[1]);
        System.out.println("ascendingNumbers - " + obj[1] + " in " + Arrays.toString((int[]) obj[0]));
        System.out.println("Expect: " + obj[2] + " --> got: " + instance.ascendingNumbers((int[]) obj[0], (int) obj[1]));
        assertEquals((int) obj[2], instance.ascendingNumbers((int[]) obj[0], (int) obj[1]));
    }
}
```

For testing purpose I am not using parametherized tests here but it should still work... The Problem is, that the result I am expecting is the same as the result of the function that I am testing but it does still say it is not the same... 
I know that it has to be correct because in the line with "Expect" I get 2 equal values...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly,* the `KniffelTableModel` instance is *stateful* and the `KniffelTableModel.ascendingNumbers()` does not produce equal results for subsequent calls with the same arguments.

Or it may modify the input array.

You can rewrite the test so that `KniffelTableModel.ascendingNumbers()` is called only once per use case, i.e.:

```
KniffelTableModel instance = new KniffelTableModel();
for (Object[] obj : testData) {
    System.out.println((int) obj[1]);
    System.out.println("ascendingNumbers - " + obj[1] + " in " + Arrays.toString((int[]) obj[0]));

    final int result = instance.ascendingNumbers((int[]) obj[0], (int) obj[1]);

    System.out.println("Expect: " + obj[2] + " --> got: " + result);
    assertEquals((int) obj[2], result);
}
```

Please inspect the `KniffelTableModel` class for the state-variables, such as:

- Non-final fields,
- Non-final static fields,
- Fields of mutable-class types,
- Usages of non-final statics from other classes.

Please post the code of the `KniffelTableModel` class if you need additional help.